# Error when trying to use pickle and multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle

I'm trying to use multiprocessing to run my code in Python 3.7, but met a problem. There is an error when I try to run my code:

```py
Can't pickle local object 'mm_prepare_run.<locals>...
```

I understand it's a problem with [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), but I didn't find a proper answer how to resolve this issue.

My simple code is below. Could you advise how I can solve the problem?

```
import multiprocessing
import copy
from pathlib import Path

proc_mrg = multiprocessing.Manager()
num_cpu = 8   # number of CPU


def prepare_run(config):
    din['config'] = config
    din_temp = copy.deepcopy(din)
    dout_list.append(proc_mrg.dict({}))

    #process = multiprocessing.Process(target=Run_IDEAS_instance_get_trajectory,args=(din_temp, dout_list[-1]))  
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=Run_IDEAS_instance_get_trajectory(din_temp, dout_list[-1]))
    proc_list.append(process)

    for job in proc_list:
        job.start()
```

Comment: Your `Run_IDEAS_instance_get_trajectory` returns a object that pickle fails to serialize. You will have to share the code of this function in order to get help.

Comment: I added this function, but it starts from print("Start") and I even can't see this "Start" on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `Process`, in `prepare_run` you are *calling* `Run_IDEAS_instance_get_trajectory` instead of just passing it as a reference.
And since that function does not return a result, the `target` of the `Process` is `None`.

Use this instead:

```
process = multiprocessing.Process(
    target=Run_IDEAS_instance_get_trajectory,
    args=(din_temp, dout_list[-1])
)
```

Functions in Python are first class objects of the callable type.
See the "Data model" chapter in the Python language reference.

**Edit:**

From your comment, I can see that you are running this code on ms-windows.
On this platform it is *required* that you run process creation inside a `if __name__ == "__main__"` block! Because of how `multiprocessing` works on this platform, python has to be able to *import* your script without side effects such as starting a new process. See the "programming guidelines" section in the documentation for `multiprocessing`.

Comment: Roland, thank you for your advise. Actually I used this as well (see my code), but I have the same result:                                                                                                                         Can't pickle local object 'mm_prepare_run. <locals>.Run_IDEAS_instance_get_trajectory'
File  
 "...\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60

Comment: @AlinaBelova See updated answer.

Comment: Roland, thank you for explanation - now looks like I better understand a reason of my problem. I'm calling multiprocessing for the function that is calling from another file (function) as well that calling (as import) from one more file (let's say 3 levels). So, in my case __main__ is another file. Can you recommend how I can locally re-define __name__ for calling my multiprocessing ?

Comment: Roland, problem is fixed, thanks!